Why does Vinyl Carbocation not rearrange?
I have read the answer to another similar question and they have said that the 'allyl' carbocation formed is actually a 'twisted allyl' carbocation. But why can't this conformer rotate about it's sigma bond for the more stable conformer to form.
Also the twisted conformer is still more stable than tye vinyl carbocation.

Also I agree with the second answer the course suggested by them should not occur.
Edit: on reading a bit more about vinyl carbocations I have understood that the couse drawn in red is in fact not suggested by the answer.my question of why the course in green in so bad still remains unanswered.

I have added the link to the other question in the question body. Please provide the link so the readers can understand the context. Moreover, your "second" answer could be the readers first. Please clarify which answer you are referring to. You can edit that in the question body.

Sorry I don't understand what you mean by clarifying 'second' answer don't answers appear in same order for all users?

@DivyanshArora The order of the answers depends on a number of factors, and no it  is not the same for all users. It may even vary for the same user on different views of the question and answer, for instance if there have been new votes, or an answer has been accepted. So please clarify what you mean by 'second' answer.
